# Obtain Angular initialization parameter?

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine

I am using App Engine as backend and created a Angular frontend. In the Angular app I got one form with some initialization parameter (stored in the javascript file). Now I put the parameter as a static file. However sending the initialization parameter using the rest API is slow.

Here is one example of initialization parameter

```
$scope.colors = [
        'YELLOW',
        'GREEN',
        'RED',
        'BLUE'
    ];
```

I was thinking if that the javascript file, which stored the initial parameter,  can be created on the fly. My backend is using Jinja2 but I am not sure if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does that mean "put the parameter as a static file"? Overall, I think the question is too vague and broad. Try to anchor it with at least some code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the question and hope that would help you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, you need to initialize a kind of config file on the loading of the app. so, you can always do this:

```
angular
 .module("someApp")
 .run(["$http",function($http){
      $http.get(url,function(){/*callback function to store the config, could be saved in the $rootScope which is accessible from all controller.*/});
});
```

or, you can store the config in a factory (or provider), and initialize it in the run function as shown below.

```
angular
 .module("someApp")
 .factory("$config",function(){/*factory*/});

angular
 .module("someApp")
 .run(["$config",function($config){
    $config.getConfig();
});
```

and then the parameters as promises will be saved in the $config factory, like          :
`$config.toolbarColor;`//is black for exmaple

Comment: Thanks. Using that would work but the extra API call would increase the load time. Am I right?